# merge multiple arrays of objects into one array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need your help. I have the following line of code which returns me one or more arrays depending on the checkbox that is clicked.

So far everything ok.

```
selected.forEach(langsel => {
                let filtered = person.filter(pers => pers.language == langsel);
            })
```

selected and I do not report the other variables for simplicity in reading.

For example I get:

> First array: [{id: "2", name: "Tomas Addreh", language: "English"},{id: "6", name: "Mark Addreh", language: "English"}];
>
> Second array: = [{id: "15", name: "Alex Atres", language: "Spanish"}, {id: "1", name: "Mark Sertoj", language: "Spanish"}, id: "12", name: "Martha Forrest", language: "Spanish"];

These are two separate arrays; in the sense that if I click the checkbox of interest I get the first array, if I click a second checkbox (always leaving the first checkbox checked) I get the array related to the second checkbox **losing** the first related to the previously clicked checkbox.

I don't want the former to be lost but I want **them to be merged into one array**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this requirement by using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method. I added the descriptive comments in the below code snippet.

Try this **:**

```js
// Input person array
const person = [{
    id: "2", name: "Tomas Addreh", language: "English"
}, {
    id: "6", name: "Mark Addreh", language: "English"
}, {
    id: "15", name: "Alex Atres", language: "Spanish"
}, {
    id: "1", name: "Mark Sertoj", language: "Spanish"
}, {
    id: "12", name: "Martha Forrest", language: "Spanish"
}];

// Initializing an array to get selected checkbox values.
const selectedPerson = [];

// getSelectedPerson() method invoke on checkbox value change.
function getSelectedPerson(event) {

// This line of code is used to push the selected languages from the checkboxes on checked into an array and remove if checbox unchecked.
  event.target.checked ? selectedPerson.push(event.target.value) : selectedPerson.splice(selectedPerson.indexOf(event.target.value), 1);
  
  // If there is any checbox selected then it will go inside this condition.
  if (selectedPerson.length) {
    // To filtered out the person array based on the languages available in selectedPerson array.
    const filtered = person.filter(({ language }) => selectedPerson.includes(language));
    // Assignign a result into a "result" div
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filtered, null, 2);
  } else {
    // else case
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = [];
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="english" name="english" value="English" onchange="getSelectedPerson(event)">
<label for="english"> English</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="spanish" name="spanish" value="Spanish" onchange="getSelectedPerson(event)">
<label for="spanish"> Spanish</label><br>

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to merge them and aren't worried about collisions, I would use concat.

`array1.concat(array2)` will solve your problem.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

If you want some logic on the merge, there are many other ways to do it, but the best approach most likely depends on what the logic is.